# Problems with wget retrieving file from box.com

Tags: wget

So we use `wget` to grab a file off of one of our supplies servers once a day, instead of using there own server they are now hosting the file on box.com

I updated the `wget` command, however it is not working. Any insight on what I need to change would be much appreciated.

```
wget -q https://companyname.app.box.com/index.php?rm=box_download_shared_file&shared_name=wt7o9hcasdjashdkar2xs3zkrsih2jnetoq0b&file_id=f_145208187622 -O datafeed.xls
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL needs to be in quotes to escape the &

```
wget -q "https://companyname.app.box.com/index.php?rm=box_download_shared_file&shared_name=wt7o9hcasdjashdkar2xs3zkrsih2jnetoq0b&file_id=f_145208187622" -O datafeed.xls
```

Comment: I don't know why your Q and A has not received much upvotes. But, I looked at the format and after working on this for 2 hours, this is the only solution I came across that worked